# Appropriate tool to populate with database content and allows you to edit it

Tags: c#

I have a table with a low quantity of rows (max 10 rows).

I need to show it's content to the user and allows him to edit it then click on a button which will make an updated in the database with the edited content.

I tried to use *ListViewItem* and populated it with a *MySqlDataReader*, but as it's not a container, I can't add buttons.
Once I used *DataGridView* but as it has a low amount of content I don't think it's worth to use *DataGridView*.

What would be the best tool to accomplish this task?

Comment: Can you clarify the statement DataGridView has a low amount of content?  I think DataGridView is perfect for what you are wanting.

Comment: I used to use *DataGridView* only for a *LARGE* amount of content (rows on the database's table). Is it ok to use it for just 10 rows or less? Isnt it too heavy ?

Comment: With a small amount of data it might seem clunky and heavy but it provides the functionality you need so use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, the `DataGridView` is the ideal choice here.  Use a `MySqlDataAdapter` to populate a `DataTable` and then bind that to a `DataGridView` via a `BindingSource`.  The user can make all the changes to the data they want and then you save the changes back to the database using the same data adapter.

Comment: I remember now that I've used *DataGridView* with buttons and editable (same thing I need here). But it was a lot of rows and was *WEB Asp.NEt*. For add buttons and etc... All the same thing ?

Comment: If it was an ASP.NET app then it wasn't a `DataGridView`, which is a Windows Forms control.  It may have been a `GridView`, which is an ASP.NET Web Forms server control, but that's a completely different control, although it serves a similar purpose.  There's nothing "heavy" about a `DataGridView`.  It's specifically designed for performance, i.e. everything is just drawn on and you only ever have one embedded control at a time when you're editing a cell.  I can tell you that a `DataGridView` is well suited to your task and much better than a `ListView`.

Comment: How could I update with the same *MySQLDataAdapter* ? To show the content I'll create a method that returns a *DataTable* then binds it to the *DataGridView*.

Comment: Whether you use the same data adapter depends on where it's created.  If you have a separate data access layer then it might not be the same one each time but if your data access code is in the form then it should be.  Regardless, to save the changes you call `Update` on an adapter.  If you have set the `SelectCommand` of that adapter then you can use a command builder to generate the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand`, otherwise you'll have to create them yourself.  Examples of both here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases

Comment: could you take a look, please? Here it's well explained the DAL.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818897/update-database-with-datagridview-edited-content